# android Intent getextras from two classes

Tags: java, android

I have the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nom);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();//from class 1
    Bundle extras2=getIntent().getExtras();//from class/
    name.setText(extras.getString("nom"));//if methode in class1 works
    name.setText(extras2.getString("nombank"));//if methode in class 2 works
}
```

But i get empty `name`.

I need to get pass two Strings from two different classes(class1 and class2) to the `MainActivity.java`

Comment: two class cannot start a same activity so `extras2` and `extras` are same

Comment: Do you mean your MainActivity may call from 2 different activity and both sent different data..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass extra with same key and get in activity

Class 1

```
Intent class1 = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
class1.putExtra("same_key","class 1 string");
```

Class 2

```
Intent class2 = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
class2.putExtra("same_key","class 2 string");
```

MainActivity

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    //Called from Class1 show "class 1 string" 
    //Called from Class2 show "class 2 string" 
     name.setText(extras.getString("same_key"));
```

If MainActivity will called from Class 1 extra string will be from Class 1, if from Class 2 extra string will be from Class2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of that.
Just do as shown below:

```js
name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nom")); 
name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nombank"));
```

That's It, This is All You Need.

But you can't Put Two Intent Extras in the Same TextView.
You can Only USE ONE

Comment: i 've  just run this code and it works thanks
name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nom"));